# How to have the complete bom?

Tags: sql

i actually have a recursive sql query that give me the first 2 level of a bom but i need the complete one. I tried to create procedure to get all the the bom first level of all my product. From here i don't know what i can do next. Do you have any idea or what do you think would be the best way to do it?

With you advice, i wrote 2 queries.
The first one work but i want to avoid repetitions

```
WITH temp_table AS (

    SELECT *
    FROM A
            INNER JOIN B ON ...
            INNER JOIN C ON ...
            INNER JOIN D ON ...
            INNER JOIN E ON ...
            INNER JOIN F ON ...
    WHERE cond 1 AND cond 2 AND cond 3


      UNION ALL

      SELECT *
    FROM A
            INNER JOIN B ON ...
            INNER JOIN C ON ...
            INNER JOIN D ON ...
            INNER JOIN E ON ...
            INNER JOIN F ON ...
    WHERE cond 4 AND cond 2 AND cond 3
)
    SELECT * FROM temp_table option (maxrecursion 0)
```

So i wrote this one to but the problem here is that i don't have all the level of my bom

```
WITH
    --join all the tables
    join_table AS (
        SELECT *
    FROM A
            INNER JOIN B ON ...
            INNER JOIN C ON ...
            INNER JOIN D ON ...
            INNER JOIN E ON ...
            INNER JOIN F ON ...
    WHERE cond 2 AND cond 3
          
          --ORDER BY stko.WRKAN
          ),

    --get the bom on the prodcut
    principal_BOM AS(
        SELECT * FROM join_table WHERE cond 1 ),

    --get the bom of all the semi or finished products in the main bom
    bom_of_item AS(
        SELECT join_table.* FROM join_table INNER JOIN principal_BOM ON join_table.Article= principal_BOM.Bom_Composant
        )
    
    --get the first level
    SELECT * FROM principal_BOM
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM bom_of_item
```

Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Define a common table expression that represents the base case of your recursive query. This will retrieve the first level of the BOM

Comment: then write the recursive part of the query that builds upon the base case it will retireve the subsequent level of bom

Comment: combine the base case and recursive parts to form the complete recursive query it will retrieve all level of the bom

Comment: If you need any help in query then you can sent here will try my best to help you

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I wrote some queries

Comment: @EmmBr https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

you have worked on the first two levels of the BOM but you want to extend it for  all levels inclusion here the query is

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp_table AS (
    -- --Anchor query (first level)-- --
    SELECT *
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON ...
    INNER JOIN C ON ...
    INNER JOIN D ON ...
    INNER JOIN E ON ...
    INNER JOIN F ON ...
    WHERE cond 1 AND cond 2 AND cond 3
    
    UNION ALL
    
    -- --Recursive query (subsequent levels) -- --
    SELECT join_table.*
    FROM join_table
    INNER JOIN temp_table ON join_table.Article = temp_table.Bom_Composant
)
SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```